# Individual Labels update value when swiped

Tags: ios, swift

Ive got my swipe functionality working now on individual labels due to some great help! Now I just need each of those labels to update individually when swiped, so each label has its own seperate counter and doesnt effect the other ones.

heres my code:

import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var counter = 0

    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var label3: UILabel!

    var counters: [UILabel: Int] = [:]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for label: UILabel in [label1, label2, label3] {

            counters[label] = 0

            for direction: UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection in [.up, .down, .left, .right] {

                let swipeGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didSwipe(_:)))
                swipeGesture.direction = direction
                label.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGesture)
                label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                label.isMultipleTouchEnabled = true
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func didSwipe(_ gestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {



        guard let label = gestureRecognizer.view as? UILabel else { return }

        debugPrint("\(gestureRecognizer.direction)")

        switch gestureRecognizer.direction {

        case .up:
            counters[label] = counters[label]! + 5
            print(counters)

        case .down:
            counters[label] = 0
            print(counters)

        case .left:
             counters[label] = counters[label]! - 1
            print(counters)

        case .right:
             counters[label] = counters[label]! + 1
            print(counters)

        default:
            label.text = "0"
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Are you wanting each label to have its own counter based on it being swiped compared to the others?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm trying to achieve. I'm also wanting to be able to add more labels, as many as needed and have that functionality to each one created

Comment: And currently your counters variable is just staying the same for all of them? I just want to make sure I understand correctly.

Comment: I'm very very new to coding so whatever is the simplest way to make it happen. If that needs to be changed or replaced by something more functional then that's ok. In my last question, the person who was a great help set that up briefly for me.

Comment: It could very well be that that variable will work fine and i just havent figured out how to apply it to the labels to get them to work individually.

Comment: What I am asking is if you swipe one label does the counter label increase for all of them?

Comment: No, so if I swipe label1 it increases or decreases based on swipe direction, label2 counter will be unaffected by that, so if I swipe label2 next, it will change without affected what's already happened to label1 etc.

Comment: Okay I see what you mean. You just need to display the update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call

```
label.text = "\(counters[label]!)"
```

At the end of your switch statement. This should work.

Comment: Ive added it to the bottom, its now throwing an error : Cannot assign value of type 'Int' to type 'String?'. I assume thats an easy fix

Comment: Just do some string interpolation. You can place your value inside quotes. "\\(counters[label]!)"

Comment: Thanks, that worked as it does in the above code example. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I see how, set the label of the text at the end of the gesture.

label.text = “(counters[label]!)”

For example,

```
@objc func didSwipe(_ gestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

    guard let label = gestureRecognizer.view as? UILabel else { return }

    debugPrint("\(gestureRecognizer.direction)")

    switch gestureRecognizer.direction {

    case .up:
        counters[label] = counters[label]! + 5
        print(counters)

    case .down:
        counters[label] = 0
        print(counters)

    case .left:
         counters[label] = counters[label]! - 1
        print(counters)

    case .right:
         counters[label] = counters[label]! + 1
        print(counters)

    default:
        counters[label] = 0
    }

    label.text = “\(counters[label]!)”
}
```

Comment: How and where do i do that exactly? label.text = counters? or slightly differently based on how its set up with the UILabel:Int?

Comment: This is precisely it. The interpolation is right there at the bottom. This will allow your int to be in a string.

Comment: Thanks! This code worked perfectly, i had to copy and paste it for it to do it but its good! Thanks so so much!